# Wrap each list array in a Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I am trying to get each Post lists wrapped in the href so it can be clicked on. Basically when I try to click on each Posts, it does not work until I hover my mouse close to the top of each posts before it works.

Below is my code and also an image of what I mean:

JS:

```
function getPosts(data) {
    var $output = $('<ul class="posts" data-role="listview" data-filter="true">')
    $.each(data.posts,function(i, val) {   
        $('<li><a href="#devotionpost" onclick="showPost(' + val.id + ')"</a>').append([$("<h3>", {html: val.title}),$("<p>", {html: val.excerpt})]).appendTo($output);
        if ( i == 3 ) return false;
       // return (postlimit-- > 1);
    });
    $('#postlist').empty().append($output);
}

function showPost(id) {
    $('#mypost').html('<span class="img_spin">Loading post...</span>');
    $.getJSON('http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/?json=get_post&post_id=' + id + '&callback=?', function(data) {
        var posts='';
        posts += '<h3>' + data.post.title + '</h3>';
        posts += data.post.content;
        $('#mypost').html(posts);
    });
}
```

Image:
[image]

If you look at the image, when i hover my mouse close to the top edge of the Post, then the URL at the bottom shows and that works but any where else does not work.

Comment: Add your `onclick` to the `li` or a `div` containing the elements. Not necessary to use an `a` tag to do the click handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the Chrome *Elements* tab in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/H3k4C/) the JavaScript is generating invalid HTML because of mismatched closing elements.

Using an example *posts* of `var posts = { "posts" : [ {"id":"1", "title":"lorem", "excerpt":"foo"}, {"id":"2", "title":"ipsum", "excerpt":"bar"} ] }`

This `'<li><a href="#devotionpost" onclick="showPost(' + val.id + ')"</a>'` is resulting in the broken first child of the following `<li>`:

```
<li>
    <a href="#devotionpost" onclick="showPost(1)" < a></a>
    <h3>lorem</h3>
    <p>foo</p>
</li>
```

Depending on exactly what you want to wrap in the anchor element, you could just build the post `<li>` like in [**this updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/H3k4C/1/) or see code below:

```
$.each(data.posts,function(i, val) {
    $output.append('<li><a href="#devotionpost" onclick="showPost(' + val.id + ')"><h3>' + val.title + '</h3><p>' + val.excerpt + '</p></a></li>');
});
```

Or if you want to have a little less string concatenation, you could use [`.wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)

```
$.each(data.posts,function(i, val) {
    var $post = $('<li><h3>' + val.title + '</h3><p>' + val.excerpt + '</p></li>');
    $post.wrapInner('<a href="#devotionpost" onclick="showPost(' + val.id + ')"></a>');
    $output.append($post);
});
```

Or keeping your `.append()` approach:

```
$.each(data.posts,function(i, val) {
    var $post = $('<li/>').append([$("<h3>", {html: val.title}),$("<p>", {html: val.excerpt})]).wrapInner('<a href="#devotionpost" onclick="showPost(' + val.id + ')"></a>');
    $output.append($post);
});
```

*Note:* The string concatenation approach, combined with a *single* `.append()` is the [best performing code](http://jsperf.com/string-concat-single-append-vs-multiple-append/2).

Comment: Thanks Andyb for this explanation. You have just added an example of what i had tried earlier and I see where I went wrong. I will update this code as soon as I correct the errors.

Comment: done some testing from your recommendation and all looking good. Thanks.

I will raise another question on use of count or if statement so it displays first 6 posts and on a click function, it appends the next 6 posts

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, your lists are floating. You should use a clearfix technique to make "A" element box include the list. You also should know that by standard "A" elements are not allowed to contain block elements and as far as internet explorer 9 (didn't check in 10 or 11)  "A" will not work the way you intended.

Possible workaround:
    `<div style="position:relative">

       <ul>

         <li></li>

       <ul>

       <a style="position:absolute;display:block;top:0;bottom:0;left:0:right:0;" href="#"></a>

     <div>`